# TweenMax Repeat GSAP

Tags: javascript, gsap

I want to repeat this animation at the end. repeat(); is not working for multiple objects. It is created with TweenMax (GSAP). All divs have svg images & in JS I define TweenMax.from & TweenMax.to for the animation.

```js
TweenMax.from(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut});
TweenMax.to(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:3})

TweenMax.from(".call", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:3});
TweenMax.to(".call", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:6})

TweenMax.from(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:6});
TweenMax.to(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:9})
```

```css
.demo{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
}
.logo{
 
 width: 66px;
}
.chat{
 
 width: 31px;
 margin: 17px;
}
.call{
 
 width: 30px;
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-left: 17px;
}
.whatsapp{
 
 width: 35px;
 margin-top: 14px;
 margin-left: 17px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="demo"> <img class="logo" alt="circle" src="https://svgshare.com/i/7Ah.svg"/> </div>
<div class="demo"> <img class="chat" alt="chat" src="https://svgshare.com/i/798.svg"/> </div>
<div class="demo"> <img class="call" alt="call" src="https://svgshare.com/i/7B2.svg"/> </div>
<div class="demo"> <img class="whatsapp" alt="whatsapp" src="https://svgshare.com/i/7At.svg"/> </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add a "repeat" to any of those tweens, but if you're looking to repeat an entire sequence of tweens, then check out TimelineMax. You'll love it. https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax and here's a must-read article that could revolutionize your animation workflow: https://css-tricks.com/writing-smarter-animation-code/

Answer (score 2):

You could put the entire thing in a function that recalls itself onComplete of the final animation like so:

```
const animation = () {
  TweenMax.from(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, 
  ease:Back.easeOut});
  TweenMax.to(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:3})

  TweenMax.from(".call", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut, 
  delay:3});
  TweenMax.to(".call", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:6})

  TweenMax.from(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, 
  ease:Back.easeOut, delay:6});
  TweenMax.to(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:9, onComplete: () => {animation()} })
}
```

However the best way would be to use a repeat: -1 inside the constructor of a [TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to recreate your animation exactly.  But this code should give the conceptual idea of how to do it with TimelineMax.

```
 // put the timeline in a function, so that it does not automatically start affecting the DOM before you want it to.
 const getTimeline = () => {
   // the timeline methods are chain-able
   let timeline = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1, paused: true})  // repeat setting for infinite repeat
    timeline.set('.chat', {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1}) //set the elements in their start positions
            .set('.call', { {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1})
            .addLabel('one', 3) //add labels for other sections of the timeline
            .addLabel('two', 2) //the first param is the element, the second is the time at which the label starts
            .addLabel('three', 4)
            .to('.chat', 0.7, { scale:1, opacity: 1, ease:Power2.easeOut}, 'one')  // this tween will start where you set label one to start
            .to('.chat', 0.7, { scale:0, opacity: 0, ease:Power2.easeOut}, 'two')
            .to('.call', 0.7, { scale:1, opacity: 1, ease:Power2.easeOut}, 'three')
            .to('.call', 0.7, { scale:0, opacity: 0, ease:Power2.easeOut}, 6) // You don't have to use a label. You can just set the time where you want this tween to start
   return timeline
}

let timeline = getTimeline()
timeline.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple tweens you can just do something like this

```
function chatTween() {
  var tl = new TimelineMax()
  tl.from(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut})
    .to(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:3})
  return tl
}

function callTween() {
  var tl = new TimelineMax()
  tl.from(".call", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut})
    .to(".call", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:3})
   return tl
}

function whatsappTween() {
  var tl = new TimelineMax()
  tl.from(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut})
    .to(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:3})
   return tl
}
```

And you can add it in the main timeline like this and make it repeat like so

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({ repeat: -1 })
tl.add(chatTween(), 0)
  .add(chatTween(), 2)
  .add(chatTween(), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to repeat entire animation then this will do

```
tl=gsap.timeline({repeat:-1})
tl.from(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut});
  .to(".chat", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:3})

  .from(".call", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:3});
  .to(".call", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:6})

  .from(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, opacity:0, scale:0.1, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:6});
  .to(".whatsapp", 0.7, {x:0, scale:0, ease:Power2.easeOut, delay:9})
```